Is there a way to add custom matchers in Playwright using generics?
Since version 1.39 of Playwright we now have a way to create custom matchers with Typescript support that makes the old way of doing it obsolete.
With the new way we can do something like:
export const expect = base.extend({
  toVerifySomething(something: any, predicate: (it: any) => boolean) {
    // ...
  },
});

The issue with this is that we lose completion capabilities, as we need to use any:
expect("some string").toVerifySomething((it) => it); // `(parameter) it: any`

I tried using generics like in the following code snippet, but it only makes T equal to unknown.
export const expect = base.extend({
  toVerifySomething<T>(something: T, predicate: (it: T) => boolean) {
    // ...
  },
});

expect("some string").toVerifySomething((it) => it); // `(parameter) it: unknown`

Is there a way to use generics when creating custom matchers in Playwright?
When inspecting the type of expect we can see that it has a generic that matches the type of actual:
const expect: <string>(actual: string, messageOrOptions?: string | { message?: string }) => MakeMatchers<void, string, {
    toVerifySomething<T>(something: T, predicate: (it: T) => boolean): {
        message: () => string;
        pass: boolean;
    };
}>

Additionally I tried the previous way of doing it with a declare global but it doesn't seem to work with the new structure:
export const expect = base.extend({
  toVerifySomething(something: any, predicate: (it: any) => boolean) {
    // ...
  },
});

declare global {
    namespace PlaywrightTest {
        interface Matchers<R, T> {
            toVerifySomething(something: T, predicate: (it: T) => boolean): R;
        }
    }
}

expect("some string").toVerifySomething((it) => it); // `(parameter) it: unknown`

If you hover over toVerifySomething you will see something like:
(method) PlaywrightTest.Matchers<R, T = unknown>.toVerifySomething(something: string, predicate: (it: string) => boolean): void (+1 overload)

Edit: I found a workaround to make it work again using the old method:
// We need to add `<{}>` after `extend`.
export const expect = base.extend<{}>({
  toVerifySomething(something: any, predicate: (it: any) => boolean) {
    // ...
  },
});

declare global {
    namespace PlaywrightTest {
        interface Matchers<R, T> {
            toVerifySomething(something: T, predicate: (it: T) => boolean): R;
        }
    }
}

expect("some string").toVerifySomething((it) => it); // `(parameter) it: string`

As you can see it is not ideal but it is good enough.

Your question is nice. Try to remove the screenshots, and upload your code as text. People like to see code that they can copy and past in their IDE.

@TalAngel Done! I also added a workaround I found recently.
